# Replace instance variable with local variable

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

^[[1;31m./app/views/sources/_form.html.erb:136 - replace instance variable with local variable^[[0m
^[[1;31m./app/views/sources/_form.html.erb:138 - replace instance variable with local variable^[[0m

What really does this mean ? And what is the procedure to get rid of this warning ?

```
<div id="book-container">
<label class="control-label" style="width: auto; font-weight:bold;">"selected books<span class="
red-star"> *</span></label>
<div "book-container">
<% if @chapter.nil? %>
<%= select_tag('book_ids',
options_for_select(@books.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id, {title: s.name}] }, params[:book_ids]),
{multiple: true, prompt: "hello:", style: "width: auto;",
data: {'multiselect-opts' => {height: '400px'}}}) %>
<% else %>
<% selected_books = @chapter.get_selected_books %>
<%= select_tag('book_ids',
options_for_select(@books.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id, {title: s.name}] }, selected_books),
{multiple: true, prompt: "Hello", style: "width: auto;",
data: {'multiselect-opts' => {height: '400px'}}}) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the template that generated this error message please?

Comment: Got these messages using rails best practices.

Comment: You still need to show us the code for template that is listed in the error messages above.

Comment: Have added code for lines 136 and 138.

Comment: /app/views/ad_sources/_form.html.erb:47 Looks like the first instance of the bug is on line 47

Also - you need to tell me which line is 136 :)

Comment: it will help if you point out the line numbers :)

Comment: your partial view code is using `@books` which is instance variables check where the partial called it should not send any type of instance variables over here it should be like `<%=render partial: "_form", locals: {books: @books}%>` so it should be use `books` not `@books`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to use this code in a partial, then try to pass the `@placements`, `@sites` and other instance variables as locals.

So when you are rendering your partial, do something like following:

`<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :placement => @placement, :sites => @sites } %>`

Then instead of using `@placement`, use `placement` in your partial and so on. 
The aim is to make the partials more reusable.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: 136 : <% if @chapter.nil? %>
138 : options_for_select(@books.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id, {title: s.name}] }, params[:book_ids]),
{multiple: true, prompt: "hello:", style: "width: auto;" these are the codes for 136 and 138 :)